# Form validation error message in Safari

Tags: html, input, safari

I'm using Safari version 6.0.2 and I can't figure out how to get the HTML5 form validation to work properly. My code is the following:

```
<input type="url" name="url" required />
```

If I leave the form blank or write something that isn't an Url the form doesn't submit. The problem is that I get no error message like in Chrome where it tells me that the field must be filled in. Is there any way to activate the error message in Safari without using jQuery plugins?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080166/html5-form-validation-not-working-with-iphone-android-or-safari)